# A slight modification of a given minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero (not algebraically closed).
Let $a$ be an algebraic element over $k$, and let $f=T^p+\lambda_{p-1}T^{p-1}+\cdots+\lambda_1T+\lambda_0$ be its minimal polynomial over $k$,
having degree a prime number $p \geq 3$. Denote $L=k(a)$.

Let $g=T^p+\mu_{p-1}T^{p-1}+\cdots+\mu_1T+\mu_0$, where $\mu_i \in \{ \lambda_i, -\lambda_i \}$.

> Can one obtain an interesting connection between the roots of $f$ and the roots of $g$? (I am not assuming that $k \subset L$ is Galois).

**Remark:**
What I actually wish to obtain is that $k \subset L$ is Galois. There is a nice criterion which says that if a conjugate of $a$ (another root of $f$) is in $L$, then $k \subset L$ is Galois; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118106/how-to-show-that-a-prime-degree-separable-field-extension-containing-a-nontrivia). What I hope to obtain (though I guess there is a counterexample) is that if (at least) one root of $g$ is in $L$, then $k \subset L$ is Galois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, your wish won't be fulfilled. The simplest counterexample I could think of is
$$
f=T^3-2,\qquad g=T^3+2.
$$
The number $a=\root3\of2$ has $f$ as its minimal polynomial over $k=\Bbb{Q}$. The polynomial $g$ has a root $-a\in L=k(a)$. Yet $L/K$ is not Galois, because it does not contain the other two zeros of $f$.