# When $k(a+b,c+d)\subseteq k(a,b,c,d)$ is Galois?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\mathbb{C} \subseteq K$ be a field and let $a,b,c,d \in K$.

Assume that $k(a+b,c+d)\subseteq k(a,b,c,d)=k(a+b,c+d)(a,c)$ is a finite separable field extension.

By the primitive element theorem, there exists $\lambda \in k$ such that 
$k(a+b,c+d)(a,c)=k(a+b,c+d)(a+\lambda c)$.

Further assume that:

(1) $\lambda=0$, so $a$ is a primitive element for the extension. (Is it true that then $b$ is also a primitive element for the extension?).

(2) The degree of the field extension is a prime number; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118106/how-to-show-that-a-prime-degree-separable-field-extension-containing-a-nontrivia).
(Is it possible to show that $a$ and $b$ are conjugates= have the same minimal polynomial over $k(a+b,c+d)$?).

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: If you pick any fields $F,E$ so that $k \subseteq F \subseteq E \subseteq K$ then you can always pick $a,b,c,d \in K$ so that $F=k(a+b,c+d)$ and $E=k(a,b,c,d)$. So in its full generality, the question is "how do we tell if an arbitrary extension $F \subseteq E$ is galois?" which is extremely broad unless you have further information about the fields or elements involved.

Comment: You are right. I will try to restrict my question.

Comment: Still too broad! Do you have a specific $k$ in mind? Is there a galois group that you know? Do the elements $a,b,c,d$ have any special properties?

Comment: $k=\mathbb{C}$. $\lambda=0$, so $a$ is a primitive element for the extension $k(a+b,c+d) \subseteq k(a+b,c+d)(a)=k(a,b,c,d)$. The degree of the field extension is a prime number $\geq 3$.

Comment: Do you know of any specific cases where my above questions have answers?

Comment: If a prime degree extension is galois, then the galois group must be cyclic $C_d$. Kummer theory or class field theory might be useful.

Comment: As it is, you need to change your question to something more specific.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your comment about prime degree in an answer? I will change my question, so that the remarks will be assumptions of the question.