# Is it 'rare' that $a$ and $a+1$ are conjugate (= have the same minimal polynomial)?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Let $a \in \bar{k}-k$, $k$ is a field of characteristic zero and $\bar{k}$ is an algebraic closure of $k$.

Denote the minimal polynomial of $a$ by $m_a=m_a(t) \in k[t]$.

> Is it 'rare' that $m_a=m_{a+1}$? In other words, is it rare that $a$ and $a+1$ are conjugate?

For example, $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and $a=\sqrt{2}$. Then $m_a=t^2-2 \neq m_{a+1}$.

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: It would be better rephrase your question, to be more specific. For example, what are the conditions under what $a$ and $a+1$ are conjugate.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. (By https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118106/how-to-show-that-a-prime-degree-separable-field-extension-containing-a-nontrivia?noredirect=1&lq=1, if $k \subsetneq k(a)=L$ is of prime degree and a conjugate of $a$ is in $L$, then $L$ is Galois-- this result inspired my current question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $a$ and $a+1$ are roots of $f(X)$, then $a$ is also a root of $g(X):=f(X+1)$, hence $g$ is a multiple of $f$. By comparing the leading coefficients (if $\deg f>0$), it follows tat $g=f$. So as a function on $\Bbb Z$, $f$ is periodic, hence  bounded, hence constant ...

Comment: More generally, if $a$ and $a+b$ have the same minimal polynomial, with $b\in k$, $b\ne0$, then $f(x+b)=f(x)$, so $f$ has infinitely many roots in the algebraic closure.

Comment: Thank you. (I like both answers and have not decided which one to accept..)

Comment: @egreg, thank you. Please, how to guarantee that $a,c \in L-k$, have the same minimal polynomial? By your observation, it is necessary that $a-c \notin k$.

Comment: @user237522 I don't think that there is a different answer than “$a$ and $c$ have the same minimal polynomial” or “there is an automorphism of $L$ over $k$ sending $a$ to $c$”.

Comment: ok, thank you. Please, what if $c=a^m$ for some $m \geq 2$? Is it 'less rare' to have an automorphism of $L$ over $k$ sending $a$ to $a^m$?

Comment: For example, if $m=2$ and the degree of the mininal polynomial of $a$ is $2$ (write $f:=m_a=x^2+ax+b$), then (if I am not wrong) there are three possible cases under the assumption that $a$ and $a^2$ are conjugate: $f=x^2-1$, $f=(x-1)^2$ and $f=x^2+x+1$. I have solved $f(x) | f(x^2)$.

Comment: Only the third option yields an extension of degree $2$.

Answer (score 5):

Take an automorphism of the splitting field taking $a$ to $a+1$. Then $a+1$ goes to $a+2$, so $a+2$ is a conjugate of $a+1$, and hence of $a$. Do you see how you can reach a contradiction this way?

Comment: Thank you. So $a$ has infinitely many conjugates, which is impossible...